# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#

When trying to call my ToString() method I get the above error message.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  Here is my code:

```
public override string  ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} Pizzas @ {1:C}: {2:C}\n" +
        "{3} Cokes @ {4:C}  {5:C}\n" +
        "Order Amount: {6:C}\n" +
        "Sales Tax: {7:C}\n" +
        "Amount Due: {8:C}\n" +
        "Amount Paid: {9:C}\n" +
        "Change Due: {10:C}", numberOfPizzas, PIZZA_PRICE + 
        totalCostOfPizza, numberOfCokes, COKE_PRICE, totalCostOfCoke +
        foodAndDrinkTotal, totalSalesTax, totalAmountDue, amountPaid, +
        changeDue);
}
```

Comment: This part doesn't look right: `PIZZA_PRICE + totalCostOfPizza,`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referencing more arguments in the string format then you are providing.

By the looks of it, drop all the pluses (in the argument list not the string concatenation) and insert commas

Comment: Drop all the `+`s, *other than those joining the elements of the format string*.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Good call. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're adding things that you didn't mean to perhaps?

Try this:

```
public override string  ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} Pizzas @ {1:C}: {2:C}\n" +
        "{3} Cokes @ {4:C}  {5:C}\n" +
        "Order Amount: {6:C}\n" +
        "Sales Tax: {7:C}\n" +
        "Amount Due: {8:C}\n" +
        "Amount Paid: {9:C}\n" +
        "Change Due: {10:C}", numberOfPizzas, PIZZA_PRICE,
        totalCostOfPizza, numberOfCokes, COKE_PRICE, totalCostOfCoke,
        foodAndDrinkTotal, totalSalesTax, totalAmountDue, amountPaid,
        changeDue);
}
```